# Javascript Popup from Code Behind Without Button Onclick Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have read numerous threads and cannot figure this one out as they all relate to calling a javascript with a button click. I have a simple javascript popup that I want to call during my vb code in an asp.net project. Each time I call the javascript, the program continues on, and my variable from the popups do not get calculated.

I need the program to stop, wait for the popup reply, and then based upon the reply, continue on. What am I missing? The first one runs fine as it is conditional based upon a button OnClientClick method, but the next two are in the code behind. I need the program to stop, wait for a response, and continue based upon the response. This doesn't happen and using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript or other javascript calls as they aren't stopping the program to wait for the response. The second two do not have a button click event to trigger them, only a programming code call.

HTML Code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Payment() {
                var payment_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
                payment_value.type = "hidden";
                payment_value.name = "payment_value";
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want To Cancel this Payment?")) {
                    payment_value.value = "Yes";
                } else {
                    payment_value.value = "No";
                }
                document.forms[0].appendChild(payment_value);
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function LateFee() {
                var latefee_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
                latefee_value.type = "hidden";
                latefee_value.name = "latefee_value";
                if (confirm("This payment is over 30 days, do you want to add a Late Fee ($99.00) to this incident?")) {
                    latefee_value.value = "Yes";
                } else {
                    latefee_value.value = "No";
                }
                document.forms[0].appendChild(latefee_value);
                console.log(latefee_value)
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function LateFeePrint() {
                var latefeeprint_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
                latefeeprint_value.type = "hidden";
                latefeeprint_value.name = "latefeeprint_value";
                if (confirm("Late Fee Updated Successfully, do you want to print a Late Fee Notice?")) {
                    latefeeprint_value.value = "Yes";
                } else {
                    latefeeprint_value.value = "No";
                }
                document.forms[0].appendChild(latefeeprint_value);
            }
        </script>

<h2><%: Title %></h2>
<p class="text-danger">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" />
</p>
```

VB,net Code:

```
    If NumDays > 30 And TempLateFee <> "$99.00" Then
        Dim LateFeeValue As String = Request.Form("latefee_value")
        'Call Javascript and popup the modal
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "LateFeeCall", "LateFee()", True)
        'use the result to calculate the late fee
        If LateFeeValue = "No" Then
        ElseIf LateFeeValue = "Yes" Then
            AccountBalance = 0
            Call UpdateLateFee()
            Call GetAlarmInfo()
            Call LoadAlarmInfo()
            Call LoadBalanceInfo()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Chas, the VB code here is run during the page `build` phase and adds a script to the page being sent to the browser. So it cannot run like this.

Comment: You will need some script in the page on the client itself to begin the `validation` process. It can call server side using `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: That gives me another direction to look at, but what I have already read on this method suggests that I must do all of the code behind calculations in the javascript, and not in the vb.net code behind. This is just a simple ok/cancel modal that pops up after an item is selected and the calculation is performed. So the server side code is calling the client side modal (javascript) to ask a question and return a response.